# Api VK. Получение списка аудио из плейлиста

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, selenium, requests

```
driver.get("https://vk.com/")
time.sleep(2)

playlist_link = input("Введите URL playlist: ")
    url = f"https://api.vkontakte.ru/method/audio.get?playlist_id={playlist_link}&access_token={token}&v=5.95"
    req = requests.get(url)
    print(req.text)
    time.sleep(20)
```

Выводит ошибку:

```
{"error":{"error_code":100,"error_msg":"One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: playlist_id not integer","request_params":[{"key":"playlist_id","value":"https:\/\/vk.com\/music\/playlist\/255982184_27"},{"key":"v","value":"5.95"},{"key":"method","value":"audio.get"},{"key":"oauth","value":"1"}]}}
```

Хочу получить список аудио для дальнейшего воспроизведения.

Comment: Возможно в параметр playlist_id не нужно передавать полностью url `https://vk.com/music/playlist/255982184_27`, а только сам идентификатор `255982184_27`

Comment: Нет, выдает такую же ошибку

Comment: попробуйте посмотреть [тут](https://habr.com/ru/post/247987/) и [тут](https://habr.com/ru/post/519302/)

Comment: Читал и то и то уже(